# installing threadscope for mac m1?

Tags: haskell, apple-m1, threadscope

There seems to be literally 0 info online about this. I want to install threadscope for haskell Parallelization. the pre built binaries on https://github.com/haskell/ThreadScope/releases are for x86 (intel). I tried to build the source code too, and it doesnt work.

When i try the pre built binary:

```
ME@ME-MBP documents % ./threadscope.macOS-latest.ghc-9.2.2
dyld[3954]: Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/gtk+/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/ME/Documents/threadscope.macOS-latest.ghc-9.2.2'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/gtk+/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64))), '/usr/local/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./threadscope.macOS-latest.ghc-9.2.2
```

When i build the source code myself (the final lines as i'm installing are):

```
[ 6 of 38] Compiling Events.TestEvents
[ 7 of 38] Compiling GUI.App
[ 8 of 38] Compiling GUI.ConcurrencyControl
[ 9 of 38] Compiling GUI.DataFiles
[10 of 38] Compiling GUI.GtkExtras
[11 of 38] Compiling GUI.EventsView
[12 of 38] Compiling GUI.MainWindow
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/ME/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/894064171ba5044f814f0d855cf6a9996fb275c6016d0ad96e7110885834c41e/8.8.4/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.8.4/libHScairo-0.13.8.1-CJN2bpyQimUKJQPgfKRXra-ghc8.8.4.dylib, 0x0005): symbol not found in flat namespace (_cairo_append_path)

--  While building package threadscope-0.2.14.1 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /Users/ME/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build exe:threadscope --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Can you try building with cabal instead of stack and post the error it gives you too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it - Use cabal to install with the source code:

this will build and install the binary:

cabal --project-file=cabal.project.osx v2-install

Don't use stack for this!!

Comment: I'm kind of surprised this worked. I expected it to fail too, just with a more useful error message.

Comment: Wonder how and why this even works

Answer (score 0):

If the previous method doesn't work, try

```
cabal update

cabal install gtk

cabal install threadscope
```

works for mac/linux/windows.